# Sorting of array of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, sorting, hash

I have an array of hash, sorting by particular key not properly working,

The array of hash is:

```
@final_array = [{:Region=>"region - 1", :ItemSize=>"Box", :Price=>""}, {:Region=>"region - 1", :ItemSize=>"Pack", :Price=>""}, {:Region=>"region - 1", :ItemSize=>"ball", :Price=>""}, {:Region=>"region - 1", :ItemSize=>"ball -1", :Price=>""}, {:Region=>"region - 1", :ItemSize=>"new size", :Price=>""}, {:Region=>"region - 1", :ItemSize=>"new size 1", :Price=>""}, {:Region=>"region - 1", :ItemSize=>"wels", :Price=>""}]

@final_array = @final_array.sort_by { |x, y| x[:ItemSize] }
```

After sorting I am checking array by select query.

```
a = []

@final_array.select{ |x, y| a << x[:ItemSize] }

a
# => ["Box", "Pack", "ball", "ball -1", "new size", "new size 1", "wels"]
```

It's not properly working.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean with not working properly? `["Box", "Pack", "ball", "ball -1", "new size", "new size 1", "wels"].sort == ["Box", "Pack", "ball", "ball -1", "new size", "new size 1", "wels"] # true`

Comment: I mean after sorting by itemsize it's not coming properly. To show itemsize alone I am using select to filter the sorted key alone.

Comment: If u check the result the order should come in [ball, ball -1, Box , new size 1, pack wells],

Comment: But I didn't get expected results, Did u got my point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@final_array = @final_array.sort_by { |x, y| x[:ItemSize].downcase }
```

This makes sure that the case you pass into `sort_by` is all the same. It does not change the case of the ItemSize values.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare 2 strings for sorting with just `str1 <=> str2`, upcase letters comes before downcase letter: A B C ... Y Z a b c ... y z. That's why you get `Box` and `Pack` before `ball`.

Turn everything to the same case if you want' it case insensitive.

```
@final_array.sort_by { |x, y| x[:ItemSize].downcase }
```

Anyway, I personally don't like sorting hashed, I would better get the values I need as an array and then order that array.

```
ordered = @final_array.map{|x| x[:ItemSize] }.sort_by{|x| x.downcase }
```

Comment: Thanks arieljuod for brief explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in following way:

```
sorted_arr = @final_array.collect{|arr| arr[:ItemSize]}.sort { | a1, a2 | a1.downcase <=> a2.downcase }
```